# Django API: Revoke tokens after a certain amount of request

Tags: django, api, rest

I am trying to code an API that would receive a string or a list of strings and return my model's predictions. I use token authentication for the ease of use, however, I don't understand/can't imagine how I can limit the amount of requests a user can make on a per month basis. Or give a limited amount of requests to an anonymous user. Should I create a custom permission class ?

```
### settings.py ##
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # basics 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # API
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',       # auth
    'rest_framework_tracking',        # logging 
]
```

```
## views.py ##
class MyAPIView(APIView, LoggingMixin):
    logging_methods = ['POST', 'PUT']

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    renderer_classes = [BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer, CSVRenderer]
    parser_classes = [JSONParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, proba=False):
        query = request.POST.get('q')

        content = {
            'result': "Model predictions."
        }
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is throttling where you can either use default throttle rates or create a custom one.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '1000/day'
    }
}
```

And you can use these rates in your API.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [UserRateThrottle]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

I think this documentation may help you, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I agree with you but I thought I shouldn't write the API from the scratch also I didn't want to copy examples but here it is.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look but it seems that this method uses only the cache. Nothing is saved to the database, so I can't keep track of the requests per users on a monthly basis for example.